# chunk is not inserted in index.html in react using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have the following configuration file:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"");
var SRC_DIR_APP = path.resolve(__dirname,"src/app");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,"src");

var config = {
  entry: 
  {
    app: SRC_DIR_APP,
    vendor: ['react'],
  },

  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR,
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      minChunks: 1,
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      // 'html!' + path.join(src_path, 'index.html')
        template: path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'),
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: 'body',
    }),
  ],

  module:{
    loaders:[
      {
        test: /\.js?/,
        include: SRC_DIR_APP,
        loader: "babel-loader", 
        query:{
          presets:['react','es2015','stage-2'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
   devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

The directory structure is:
[image]

the chunks created are:

```
chunk    {0} 0.bundle.js 2.29 kB {2}
     + 1 hidden modules
chunk    {1} 1.bundle.js 2.29 kB {2}
     + 1 hidden modules
chunk    {2} app.bundle.js (app) 0 bytes {3} [initial]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 1.12 MB [entry]
     + 309 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
    chunk    {0} index.html 542 kB [entry]
        [1] ./~/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./index.html 1.43 kB {0} [built]
         + 3 hidden modules
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

but in index.html, only two scripts are added:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reactjs Basic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                    <div id="app"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="app.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Why is it so? I want to load all the chunks on demand.

Answer (score 0):

The chunks you see in your initial HTML are just the entry point of your application.

Webpack will take care of loading the other chunks on demand, only when needed by the application and user interactions.

Comment: It's not loaded.